# After migration my iOS app from Fabric to Firebase crashes still appearing in Fabric

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I did the migration asked from Google because Fabric will die next year. 
But the crashes reports still are available in Fabric. They are available in both tools: Firebase and Fabric.

Looking the Docs, they still asks you to include Fabric library in your app (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios)

So, it's something wrong in my migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase uses the same Fabric Crashlytics SDK to calculate the crashes on both Fabric and Firebase dashboards. After March 31st 2020 Fabric Crashlytics dashboard will deprecate and developer use only Firebase Crashlytics for their crash information.

Comment: What does deprecate really mean - will crashlytics data continue to appear on the fabric website or will the website vaporize on April 1, 2020? Will dSym's continue to be uploadable?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric won't show your crash after 31st march so better migrate your project from fabric to firebase.
Firebase still uses fabric Crashlytics SDK to calculate errors but the dashboard of firebase won't show anything.